# Why, discord py sending PM with send_message erroring

Tags: python, discord.py, raspberry-pi4

I've been trying for hours to get a fix for this issue from looking and hundreds of others overflow posts to documentation forums etc I cannot figure this out I'm trying to send an embed as a PM to the user specified in my function everything works except the part where it should send the private message, please help

Error

> bot has no attribute send_message

> bot has no attribute send

This is my code:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, duration_arg: str = "30", unit: str = "s", reason: str = "null"):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    moderator = ctx.message.author
    #await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('ask.{user}'.format(use), length=duration_arg))
    channel = bot.get_channel(1060922421491793981)
    duration = int(duration_arg)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id=1060693595964842165)
    units = " Null"
    if unit == "s":
        units = " seconds"
    elif unit == "m":
        units = " minutes"
    else:
        return
    length = f"{duration_arg}{units}"
    
    if unit == "s":
        wait = 1 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    elif unit == "m":
        wait = 60 * duration
        
    await ctx.send(f":mute: Muted {user} for {duration}{units}", delete_after=wait)
    await user.add_roles(role)
        #button embed---------
    view = Confirm()
    #await ctx.send('you have been **Muted**', view=view, delete_after=45)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="You have been Muted",description=f"this message will expire in **{duration_arg}** {units}",color=0x0ff0000)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Temporary Suspension for:", value=f"{user.mention}",inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Duration:", value=f"{length}", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Moderator:", value=f"{moderator.display_name}", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Summary",value=f"you can confirm this in the next {duration} {units}\n\n **if you believe this is in error appeal it and a moderator will review your temporary suspension**",inline=False)
    embedVar.set_footer(text='Booty Police | mute management',icon_url="http://canvaswrite.com/PI/pybot/attachments/server-icon-full.png")
    await bot.send_message(user.id, embed=embedVar, view=view, delete_after=wait)
    # Wait for the View to stop listening for input...
    await view.wait()
    if view.value is None:
        print('Timed out...')
    elif view.value:
        print('appealing...')
    elif view.value is appeal:
        print('Appealing...')
        channel.send("this is a test to appeal...")
    else:
        print('Cancelled...')
    #end buttons----------
    if unit == "s":
        wait = 1 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    elif unit == "m":
        wait = 60 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f":sound: {user} was unmuted",delete_after=15)
```

the value for user is defined in the command run as the user being muted not the author of the command e.g. `??mute user#1234 30 s "reason"`

Comment: "it errors" is useless information for us to try and help you. Attach the actual error to your post.

Comment: my bad. i thought i included it above the error is ```bot has no attribute send_message``` and if i change it to send it says ```bot has no attribute send```

Comment: Both of them speak for themselves. As my answer says, `send` is a method of `Messageable`, so only things that subclass `Messageable` have the `send` method. `Bot.send()` wouldn't make any sense (what would it even do?), you need a User/Member/Channel to send something to.

Comment: i just tried using user as the method of send no other examples used user for the send method which is probably why i couldnt figure this out but after trying that it seems to be working

Comment: If it's working you should mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer pointed out, you're indeed sending it to yourself instead of the user. However, the solution in that answer is still wrong.

`User.send_message()` is not a thing. You're using a function that doesn't exist, and you're surprised that it errors. The error message that you didn't include in your post should also tell you that it doesn't exist.

To send something to a channel or a user, use [`Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send).

Keep in mind that people can close their DMs to prevent you from sending them anything, which can throw another error for you, and mass-DMing will get your bot flagged for spam.

Comment: ```nameError Messageable is not defined```

Comment: It's a class, you need something that subclasses `Messageable`....